# Computer keeps 'restarting because of a problem': setPowerState timed out?

Tags: macos, catalina, kernel-panic

When I leave my 2019 MacBook Pro (on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 Beta (19D49f)) for a while I find that when I return, rather than just logging in again, I have to 'boot up' the laptop.

I then get a message 'your computer restarted because of an error', which if I share it, produces the following stack trace:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800c623e57): "AppleGFXHDADriver::setPowerState(0xffffff8043b75200 : 0xffffff7f90076bde, 0 -> 1) timed out after 10231 ms"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.80.8.0.1/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5302
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92257dbb40 : 0xffffff800bf37beb 
0xffffff92257dbb90 : 0xffffff800c06f4b5 
0xffffff92257dbbd0 : 0xffffff800c060f2e 
0xffffff92257dbc20 : 0xffffff800bedea40 
0xffffff92257dbc40 : 0xffffff800bf372d7 
0xffffff92257dbd40 : 0xffffff800bf376bb 
0xffffff92257dbd90 : 0xffffff800c6ce059 
0xffffff92257dbe00 : 0xffffff800c623e57 
0xffffff92257dbe50 : 0xffffff800c623a19 
0xffffff92257dbe60 : 0xffffff800c63adce 
0xffffff92257dbea0 : 0xffffff800c6227c8 
0xffffff92257dbec0 : 0xffffff800bf79835 
0xffffff92257dbf40 : 0xffffff800bf79361 
0xffffff92257dbfa0 : 0xffffff800bede13e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19D49f

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Sun Dec  8 22:27:29 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.80.8.0.1~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9EC18232-E356-30D5-84B8-282F31C3917B
Kernel slide:     0x000000000bc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800be00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800bd00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 24840228763018
last loaded kext at 22293762422654: >usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9011b000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 14233200063216: >!UMergeNub   900.4.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8fc78000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.10.3
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.0
com.google.santa-driver 0.9.33
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f5
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.2
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.4
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.55
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.55
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.423
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.80.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    320.49
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3430.1
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f5
>!AMultitouchDriver 3430.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f5
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.4
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.8
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f5
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

#### Update

Following a comment, here is the result of `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`:

```
> kextstat | grep -v com.apple
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  115    0 0xffffff7f83ed1000 0x6000     0x6000     com.google.santa-driver (0.9.33) C2EC6FF8-36C1-354C-ABB9-3BFA74B9A718 <6 5 3 1>
  116    3 0xffffff7f83ed7000 0xf0000    0xf0000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (6.1.0) 5DA96489-AE58-33AC-AC90-760EE66D6A0A <8 6 5 3 1>
  176    0 0xffffff7f84709000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (6.1.0) 05FAFD37-9097-3447-A282-3E0DE51C7181 <175 116 65 8 6 5 3 1>
  180    0 0xffffff7f8472b000 0x5000     0x5000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (6.1.0) 191B696D-4250-3E84-9D99-D751DD370533 <116 8 6 5 3 1>
  181    0 0xffffff7f84730000 0x6000     0x6000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (6.1.0) 1732BD29-D70C-3E92-A9BB-D27B4BDE552B <116 6 5 1>
  183    0 0xffffff7f8473b000 0x6000     0x6000     com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext (1.10.3) F29DD0CB-48D6-311A-9B69-E39CF775493C <8 6 5 2 1>
```

Comment: Can you run `kextstat | grep -v com.apple` and add the results to your post?

Comment: did you find any solution? facing exactly the same problem on mbp 16 2019

Comment: I am having the problem as well! Any luck?

Comment: I encountered the exact problem on a 16" Macbook Pro, with the latest Catalina update, 10.15.4. My output from "kextstat | grep -v com.apple" share the only common program with yours: "com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext." I wonder if that could be the problem. I have been turning Dropbox off, for now (1 day) did not see the problem. Will report back.

Comment: Same problem on a 2020 13" MBP. Using an external monitor attached to an Anker USB-C -> HDMI Adapter.

Comment: Found a long thread on Apple forums:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251225148
This tells me it's not you, it's them. ;)

Comment: Same problem, MBP 13 2020, 10.15.7. External monitor was involved.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with Catalina and my 13" MacBook Pro (2019), however, I don't share any of your third-party Kernel extensions (kext).

AppleGFXHDADriver is a driver for audio over HDMI and Displayport (therefore, also Displayport over TB3/USB-C).

I believe this is a bug which might be caused by using an external monitor. Certainly my experiments point to this because when I unplug my monitor before putting my MacBook to sleep I have yet to come across the issue.

I am actually doing more experiments e.g is the order devices go to sleep a culprit. So will update this post if I have anymore information.

Also I would encourage you to use the feedback assistant app for macOS and post the crash report and any more information regarding your setup. The more people complain and report the more likely Apple will look into the issue further.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone here, know that I feel your pain. This was happening to me for a number of months. For me, it was disconnecting from an external monitor. I finally fixed it by resetting the SMC — https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295