# Your computer was restarted because of a problem macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, restart

I just bought a new Macbook Pro 16" 2019 with macOS 10.15.4. The computer keeps restarting when sleeping. Here's the following log.

```
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff8006e91b2c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.
Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922b873900 : 0xffffff80068471e8 
0xffffff8203f9b920 : 0xffffff80067433f1 
0xffffff8203f9b990 : 0xffffff8006741c2f 
0xffffff8203f9b9e0 : 0xffffff80068442e9 
0xffffff8203f9ba20 : 0xffffff8006843b4b 
0xffffff8203f9ba50 : 0xffffff7f8a3bbced 
0xffffff8203f9ba80 : 0xffffff7f8a3d4f75 
0xffffff8203f9ba90 : 0xffffff8006e2ff59 
0xffffff8203f9baf0 : 0xffffff7f8a716602 
0xffffff8203f9bb30 : 0xffffff7f8a3c93a6 
0xffffff8203f9bbb0 : 0xffffff7f8a3c48eb 
0xffffff8203f9bc50 : 0xffffff8006e020cf 
0xffffff8203f9bcc0 : 0xffffff8006e1a770 
0xffffff8203f9bd60 : 0xffffff8006e028b9 
0xffffff8203f9bdb0 : 0xffffff8006e17e1b 
0xffffff8203f9be50 : 0xffffff8006e14294 
0xffffff8203f9bea0 : 0xffffff8006e11d40 
0xffffff8203f9bef0 : 0xffffff8006e11bd9 
0xffffff8203f9bf30 : 0xffffff8006e2d43e 
0xffffff8203f9bf70 : 0xffffff8006e2ca36 
0xffffff8203f9bfa0 : 0xffffff80066c713e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[D47CA481-C5E5-3F03-9B04-6634DF5F3121]@0xffffff7f8a3b3000->0xffffff7f8a403fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1B1F3BBB-9212-3CF9-94F8-8FEF0D3ACEC4]@0xffffff7f87111000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl2(5.1.16)[35A245F9-3261-359F-925C-59CDBE8FF584]@0xffffff7f8a70b000->0xffffff7f8a71ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(5.1.16)[B2381909-ADF2-3459-AA30-4D8D2DC2AF73]@0xffffff7f8a708000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[9D1FF279-C4A2-3344-902F-E0B22B508689]@0xffffff7f87108000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1B1F3BBB-9212-3CF9-94F8-8FEF0D3ACEC4]@0xffffff7f87111000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[D47CA481-C5E5-3F03-9B04-6634DF5F3121]@0xffffff7f8a3b3000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(5.1.16)[56FDE242-D4A6-3E8F-A81C-CE9BA61E3828]@0xffffff7f8a4c8000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006500000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 33714998995277
last loaded kext at 31293131899384: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8a720000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 33259029604480: >!UAudio  322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8da2d000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Does someone know which app/extension is causing this?

Comment: These could be hardware related.  Try the basic steps of [NVRAM and SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and see if that helps.

Comment: This is not normal, and if you've done nothing "unusual" it may be a sign that the wheels have come off. Get rid of it... call the vendor to get an RMA.

Comment: Lots of others with similar issues. Note here: 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379789/computer-keeps-restarting-because-of-a-problem-setpowerstate-timed-out
And here on Apple's forums:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251225148

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing very relevant in the log (excellent work posting it). I say that since the uptime shows that no kernel extension loaded or unloaded close to the event. Even that is circumstantial evidence and this line is the key:

> panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff8006e91b2c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.

Apple is the best resource to read these logs, so I would run the `sysdiagnose` command to capture the logs in detail and open a case with Apple Support. They have the source code to all of this and can make a call if they want to exchange your unit for a new one and analyze the hardware or if they have a couple quick items to test. The suggestion to reset the SMC one time is valid, since that is involved in the orchestration of sleep to wake.

You'll also want to do all the normal things for Kernel Panic:

1. Log everything you have connected physically.
2. Log the times when this happens (get a sysdiagnose after each event and save them somewhere off the computer).
3. Start by removing all accessories once you know how often this happens - once a day, once a week, etc... Thunderbolt connected devices can cause this and Apple Support will be able to identify that if this gets escalated to engineering and you have a couple sysdiagnose to provide.

This is a beast of a Mac and well in the premium support window where Apple is highly motivated to learn all the ways this happens. Let us know what you do, whether it's a return / exchange or you sort it out. This answer is more triage / experience than a smoking gun since getting that will take some more detail than was provided.